# How to get the longitude/latitude from a linestring

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, geopandas, multilinestring

I have a dataframe with a column of linestrings. I want to convert the linestrings to its corresponding latitude/longitude so that I can plot it with basemap. My code is as follows:

```
gdf = gpd.read_file('./call2016.shp') #read the data into a variable

streetsaslinestring = gdf.loc[: , "geometry"] #getting the linestring column
```

Next, I want to convert the data as described as lon/lat.

```
streetsinlatlong    = convert_etrs89_to_lonlat(streetsaslinestring)

streetsinlatlong.to_file('./streetslonglat.shp') #store it as .shp in order to plot it with basemap

m.readshapefile('./streetslonglat', 'streets') #read as shape file
```

The geometry column looks like this:[geometry column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZgI2.png)

How can I convert the longstring data?

Comment: What does the data in your "geometry" column look like?  E.g. what is the content of the `streetsaslinestring` variable?
Also, in the first line of code you read the shapefile using `gpd.read_file()`, but in the last line of code you read another shapefile using `m.readshapefile()` - why?

Comment: the geometry column consists of linestring elements. So for every entry in the column there exists one lineshape. In the first line I read the shape file which has various columns, e.g street names, zip codes etc. and in the last column I am using `m.readshapefile()` to plot the converted shapefile into a map using basemap.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include examples of the contents of the geometry column?

Comment: Yes of course. It contains linestring and multilinestrings. Sadly they are not iterable...

Comment: Update: So I used a different approach: 
`stations = pd.read_csv(path) `

#transforming longitude and latitude to an other projection
`geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(stations['lon'], stations['lat'])] `
`crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'} `
`geoDF_stations = gpd.GeoDataFrame(stations, crs=crs, geometry=geometry) `
`geoDF_stations_new = geoDF_stations.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:25830'}) `

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply use

```
Lats, Lons = LineStringObject.coords.xy
```

It will return the latitude and longitude array separately.